# Laravel problem when editing record from admin portal

Tags: laravel

I have website build from another programming on laravel

Website contain one page + registration form + admin control panel

When user registration on form record save and I can browse form admin side

But when I try edit the record and save give me this error

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate/^[19][09]*$/ does not exist.
```

https://maysoor.sa/admin/driver/17

```
   Bad Method Call
    Did you mean Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validate() ?
    
    // Path of page 
    
    Illuminate\Validation\Validator::__call
    vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:1292
    
    1292 ==>  throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM14R.jpg)

Comment: It seems you are trying to validate with a regex that isnt formatted right. Show us the validator code.

Comment: Add the validation code